Fast ways to count number of identical values in a row
I'm looking to count how many values in a row are identical. The idea is to be able to filter out respondents that have straightlined (ie answered all questions the same), for instance by filtering out those who have more than 90% identical answers across the cols.
I've come up with the code below, which works, but is slow on large datasets. The example below has 5 columns and 1000 rows, but my real data has 30 cols and 200.000 rows.
# define function
count_identical_values <- function(df){
  columns = c("statement_1", "statement_2", "statement_3", "statement_4", "statement_5")
  
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(identical_count = case_when(
      # all NA, then NA
      all(is.na(c_across(all_of(columns)))) ~ NA_real_,
      # else, count the number of identical values
      TRUE ~ max(table(c_across(all_of(columns)))))) %>%
    ungroup()
}

# make df
df = data.frame(statement_1 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_3 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_4 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_5 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE))

# apply function
df = count_identical_values(df)

If anyone has an idea for how to speed this up, that would be great!

Are the values in your actual data all integer and NA?

Is
apply(as.matrix(df), MARGIN=1, FUN=\(x) max(tabulate(x)))

faster? (Would need some work to handle NA values, but rowSums(is.na(as.matrix(df))) == ncol(df) might find those fairly quickly ...)

Below is a vectorized function that uses collapse::fmode. It will process your "real" dataset in less than half a second and can handle any data type. It wasn't clear if NA should be included in the count, hence the incl.na argument.
rowsames <- function(df, incl.na = TRUE) {
  u <- unlist(df, 0, 0)
  m <- match(u, unique(u), NA_integer_, if (incl.na) NULL else NA)
  rowSums(`dim<-`(fmode(m, sequence(rep.int(nrow(df), ncol(df))), na.rm = TRUE,
                        use.g.names = FALSE) == m, dim(df)), na.rm = TRUE)
}

Applying it on the example data.frame:
set.seed(1548243204)

df = data.frame(statement_1 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_3 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_4 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                statement_5 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE))

rowsames(df)[1:10]
#>  [1] 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2
rowsames(df, FALSE)[1:10]
#>  [1] 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 1

Note NA is the most frequent value in the 10th row, so rowsames returns 2 for that row if incl.na is set to TRUE and 1 otherwise.
df[1:10,]
#>    statement_1 statement_2 statement_3 statement_4 statement_5
#> 1            5           5           4          NA           2
#> 2            4           3           5           5           5
#> 3            5           5          NA           5          NA
#> 4            4           5           2           1           5
#> 5            3           4           4           4           3
#> 6            3          NA           3           1           1
#> 7           NA           4          NA           2           4
#> 8           NA           1           4           3           3
#> 9            4           2           4           3           4
#> 10           2          NA          NA           4           5



my real data has 30 cols and 200.000 rows

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 6e6, 1), 2e5, 30, 0,
                           list(NULL, paste0("statement_", 1:30))))
system.time(rowsames(df))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.41    0.03    0.43


Additional Benchmarking
Extending @RonakShah's benchmarking:
set.seed(3452)

df = data.frame(statement_1 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_3 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_4 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_5 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE))


fun_dplyr <- function(df) {
  columns = c("statement_1", "statement_2", "statement_3", "statement_4", "statement_5")
  
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(identical_count = case_when(
      # all NA, then NA
      all(is.na(c_across(all_of(columns)))) ~ NA_real_,
      # else, count the number of identical values
      TRUE ~ max(table(c_across(all_of(columns)))))) %>%
    ungroup()
}

fun_apply <- function(df) {
  apply(as.matrix(df), MARGIN=1, FUN=\(x) max(tabulate(x)))
}

fun_dapply <- function(df) {
  collapse::dapply(df, \(x) max(tabulate(x)), MARGIN = 1)
}

Timings:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # fun_dplyr = fun_dplyr(df), # too slow
  fun_apply = fun_apply(df),
  fun_dapply = fun_dapply(df),
  rowsames = rowsames(df)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#>   fun_apply 298.4000 327.0602 355.26551 352.78755 379.27705 433.5157   100
#>  fun_dapply 235.7283 261.1802 300.46456 287.33650 335.46850 442.8762   100
#>    rowsames  34.4906  36.1296  37.61214  37.16805  38.68065  47.0696   100


Nice, a 10-fold improvement on what was already about a 300-fold speedup ...

You may use collapse::dapply which will be faster.
collapse::dapply(df, \(x) max(tabulate(x)), MARGIN = 1)

to handle all NA values you may use hablar::max_ function which returns NA when all the values are NA.
Benchmarks :
set.seed(3452)

df = data.frame(statement_1 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_3 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_4 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                statement_5 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1e5, replace = TRUE))


fun_dplyr <- function(df) {
    columns = c("statement_1", "statement_2", "statement_3", "statement_4", "statement_5")
    
    df %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(identical_count = case_when(
        # all NA, then NA
        all(is.na(c_across(all_of(columns)))) ~ NA_real_,
        # else, count the number of identical values
        TRUE ~ max(table(c_across(all_of(columns)))))) %>%
      ungroup()
}

fun_apply <- function(df) {
  apply(as.matrix(df), MARGIN=1, FUN=\(x) max(tabulate(x)))
}

fun_dapply <- function(df) {
  collapse::dapply(df, \(x) max(tabulate(x)), MARGIN = 1)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fun_dplyr = fun_dplyr(df), 
  fun_apply = fun_apply(df), 
  fun_dapply = fun_dapply(df), 
  times = 10L
)

which returns
Unit: milliseconds
       expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  fun_dplyr 125572.7109 126954.4355 131877.4115 133178.7886 135347.5074 136411.1468    10
  fun_apply    413.7097    439.3520    476.6822    456.8837    507.4259    583.4736    10
 fun_dapply    293.8734    315.4473    380.0586    336.0351    363.5058    629.0772    10


Another implementation of row-wise tabulate using matrixStats. You can wrap the logic to filter out the straight answerers over a specific threshold in a function:
> fltr_straight <- \(x, threshold=.9) {
+   mx <- as.matrix(x) |> matrixStats::rowTabulates() |> matrixStats::rowMaxs()
+   mx/ncol(x) <= threshold
+ }

Usage
> df_fltr <- df[fltr_straight(df[1:5]), ]

Check which guys have been filtered out:
> setdiff(rownames(df), rownames(df_fltr))
[1] "171" "261" "287" "586"


Data:
set.seed(63572972)
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1000*5, replace=TRUE),
         1000, 5)
)

